# jersey 2.5 and Spring 2.5 integration not working

Tags: spring, jersey, jersey-2.0

I am trying to integrate Jersey (Version 2.x) into our current project which use's Spring 2.5. I have followed all the steps mentioned in their Spring webapp integration sample, but can't seem to get the auto wiring to work when the Jersey bean is called.

My config/class files are given below,

**WEB.XML FILE**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>com.inrev.rest.XXXSpringIntegration</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

**SPRING FILE**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>  

<bean name="myresource" class="com.xxx.rest.MyResource" autowire="byName"></bean>
```

**XXXSpringIntegration CLASS**

```
public XXXSpringIntegration() 
{
    register(RequestContextFilter.class);
    register(MyResource.class);
    System.err.println("I am getting registered");
}
```

**MyResource.class**

```
@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {

@Autowired
private IRAdminDAO adminDAO;

public MyResource()
{
    System.err.println("Getting ready now");
}

/**
 * Method handling HTTP GET requests. The returned object will be sent
 * to the client as "text/plain" media type.
 *
 * @return String that will be returned as a text/plain response.
 */
@Path("/list")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public String list() 
{
    System.err.println("Adming DAO "+adminDAO);

    return "Got it!";
}

public void setAdminDAO(IRAdminDAO adminDAO)
{
    System.err.println("Adming dao being set "+adminDAO);
    this.adminDAO = adminDAO;
}
```

}

Added configuration for adminDAO

```
<bean id="adminDAO" class="com.xxx.bm.dao.impl.IRAdminDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I am sure that the auto wiring works when Spring get's initialised, as the Syserr in the setter get's called when the file get's initialised by spring. However, when I make the API call, the adminDAO is null.

```
 http://bm.com:8080/bm/rest/myresource/list
```

What could be causing this, I have tried all other permutation combinations but somehow the autowiring doesn't seem to be working when we make the API call.

Regards

Comment: I am pretty sure that the integration of Spring and Jersey works for version 3 of Spring, not 2.5

Comment: @geoand would an older version of Jersey work with Spring 2.5? My initial suspect was the same, but I cannot find any documentation on the same, so want to be sure before jumping to jersey 1.x

Comment: I have no idea if Spring 2.5 can be integrated with Jersey. I have only used such integration with Spring 3 or newer

Comment: Where is configuration for adminDao?

Comment: @jny added the config

Comment: Migrated to the latest version of Spring 4.0.6, but still same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jersey work's fine with Spring 2.5, it's just a few jar's which were not present in my build. I am not sure if they would come with the maven build, but are certainly not present in the .zip download.

Also, there is no exceptions suggesting the jar is missing. jersey-spring3-2.11.jar being the star.